# How to get a list of instance attributes

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is there a function which will get a list of class/`__init__` attributes without having a single object. I need names of class attributes to pass it into a function. I tried to search for a solution many hours but most of them require using sth like `x = ClassName()` - in my case it produces an error (e.g. `__init__()` takes exactly 6 arguments (1 given)).
For example:

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, name, year, color):
         self.name = name
         self.year = year
         self.color = color
```

How do I get a list like:

```
list_of_attr = ['name', 'year', 'color']
```

Is it even possible?

Edit:
Adding some context to my question - I am trying to create a function which will get data from text file and convert it to a list of objects. Each line in a file contains data for one object - in above case it would be e.g. 'Volvo,1995,blue'.
I have right now two classes and two files (but expect more) and I have already created working solution but right now I have to pass names of object/instance attributes to my function in a pre-written list. I want it to be done automatically, based only on a class name.

Comment: "Is it even possible?" No, because these are instance attributes, not class attributes.

Comment: Those are *instance*, not *class*, attributes. What's the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: BTW, in Python 2 your classes should explicitly inherit from `object`, i.e., `class Car(object): ` otherwise you get old-style classes. In Python 3 all classes are new-style, but you can still use that syntax, which is handy if you want to write code that works in both versions.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm pretty new to python so I am not sure yet about the differences in a naming of objects/classes/instances etc. But to answer your question: I want to create w universal function which creates lists of objects (for different classes) from lines in different files (files are little databases for classes). I am not sure if it is clear enough

Comment: *"files are little databases for classes"* - where do they come from? What format are they in? Do you have control over that? Please [edit] the question with this context.

Comment: @jonrsharpe done - hope it is more understandable now

Comment: A little clearer, but *"I have to pass names"* - to where? For what purpose? If you're loading this from a CSV file, does it have a header row? Have you looked into `csv.DictReader`, which would turn the line `'Volvo,1995,blue'` into `{'name': 'Volvo', 'year':1995, 'color': 'blue'}`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe To function as an argument. Because, by combining them with values extracted from a text file I create a dictionary. And with a dictionary I create a specific object. Then I create a list of these objects and use it elsewhere. I have already written I am using text files (txt).

Comment: CSV files *are* text files, with values separated by commas, like yours. The extension being .txt or .csv or whatever is irrelevant.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Sorry, next time I will be more specific. Thank you for valuable comments.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are no class attributes at all on your class. Your `__init__` method sets *instance attributes*, so you can only access those names once you have an instance and `__init__` actually has run.

At that point you can the [`vars()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#vars) to get the namespace of an instance; this gives you a dictionary, so you can get the keys:

```
vars(x).keys()
```

If you were looking for what *arguments* the `__init__` method expects, you can use [`inspect.getargspec()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.getargspec) to introspect the signature. This gives you the names of all arguments, and values for any defaults (so keyword arguments). From this you can deduce the number of *required* (positional) arguments:

```
import inspect

argspec = inspect.getargspec(Car.__init__)
required = argspec.args
if argspec.defaults:
    required = required[:-len(argspec.defaults)]
```

This will include the `self` argument passed in automatically for bound methods; you can ignore that first argument with a slice:

```
method_required = argspec.args[1:]
if argspec.defaults:
    method_required = method_required[:-len(argspec.defaults)]
```

Demo:

```
>>> import inspect
>>> class Car:
...     def __init__(self, name, year, color):
...          self.name = name
...          self.year = year
...          self.color = color
...
>>> vars(Car('Volvo', 1975, 'blue'))
{'color': 'blue', 'name': 'Volvo', 'year': 1975}
>>> vars(Car('Volvo', 1975, 'blue')).keys()
['color', 'name', 'year']
>>> inspect.getargspec(Car.__init__)
ArgSpec(args=['self', 'name', 'year', 'color'], varargs=None, keywords=None, defaults=None)
```

Answer (score 2):

In short, it is not possible. You cannot get the memeber variables without having created memory for it (meaning: you have to create an object)There's an alternate approach for this, but the only thing is you need to have default values for the `__init__()` method. Take a look at this

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, name="default", year=1995, color="red"):
         self.name = name
         self.year = year
         self.color = color

members = [mems for mems in dir(Car()) if not callable(mems) and not mems.startswith("__")]
print members
```

The output

```
['color', 'name', 'year']
```

Comment: I really like your answer. I think I could live with default values for my instances. I also modified it a little bit so it exclude methods (I know I did not include any in my question): `[mems for mems in dir(Car()) if not callable(getattr(Car(),mems)) and not mems.startswith("__")]`

Comment: Although I have a problem with that solution. It automatically sorts names what is very unwanted.